# jQuery Sortable Connected Lists - Issue dragging the first time

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-sortable

I have a strage issue with my sortable lists. I have designed a portal framework in ASP.NET and jQuery and I'm using a sortable list to move gadgets from one to another placeholder (list). These two lists are connected together:

```
$(this.PlaceHolderClass).sortable({
    cursor: 'move',
    connectWith: this.PlaceHolderClass,
    handle: '.ControlToolbar',
    revert: true,
    placeholder: 'SortPlaceHolder',
    dropOnEmpty: true
}).disableSelection();
```

**this.PlaceHolderClass** has the value 'ControlPlaceHolder', which are the place holder containers (DIV) that hold my widgets/controls (see HTML bellow).

The problem I have is that when I start dragging an element from list1 to list2, I cannot drop it in list2 the first time. When I release the mouse button, the item dragged is returned in list1. When I start dragging the same item again to list2, then everything works fine. I don't know why this occures and why I'm not able to drag these items at the first time.

The HTML code I use look like this:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td style="width:50%;">
            <div id="ControlPlaceHolder$test" class="ControlPlaceHolder">
                    <div id="container$38$control" class="Control">
                        <div id="control$38$external">
                            My content here...
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </td>
        <td>
            <div id="ControlPlaceHolder$test2" class="ControlPlaceHolder"></div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Suggestions are very welcome.

Thanks,
Sead

Comment: I got the same problem. Is it solved?

Answer (score 1):

If list 2 is empty before you drag into it, you may need to set a `min-height` of the `<ul>`.

I had this problem initially and it was because an empty `ul` had no height at all and therefor couldn't recieve an item.

If this is not the case are there any errors in the console on the first failed drop?

Comment: Setting a min-height works like a charm. Thanks